# Java import org.mockito error package does not exists

Tags: java, gradle, junit, mockito

I have unit test file in java, I wanna use mockito, downloaded it, put into dependencies but still I have error **package org.mockito does not exist** when I wanna import library **import org.mockito.Mockito;**

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE")
        classpath('com.google.cloud.tools.jib:com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.plugin:1.8.0')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib'


bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile (group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation ('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1')
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+")
}
```